# How do I move the contents of a .txt file to a dictionary in TCL?

Tags: dictionary, tcl

Pretty rusty at tcl so bear with me if the solution to this questions is a fairly simple one.

I have a .txt file that contains sites and addresses with one space between them.
It looks something like this:

```
site1 address1
site2 address2
site3 address3
.
.
.
.
```

I want to read the .txt file and create a dictionary with sites as keys and values as addresses in tcl.
So my result tcl dictionary should look something like this:

dict = {"site1": "address1", "site2": "address2", ........}

How do I do this in tcl?

I only have an idea on how to implement this in Python but no clue whatsoever in tcl.

Answer (score 1):

> I have a .txt file that contains sites and addresses with one space between them.

As long as there aren't other spaces besides the ones separating the key and value strings, you just have to read the entire file in as a string and start treating it as a dict:

```
#!/usr/bin/env tclsh

set fp [open input.txt]
set mydict [read $fp]
close $fp
puts [dict get $mydict site3] ;# address3
```

Comment: Thanks for the response Shawn.
This particular code snippet that you have shown is just for site3-->address3 key-value pair. Does this mean I need to go through each one by one?

Comment: @KD0704 the others are in the dict too.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what the actual formats of the `site1` and `address1` (etc.) are. *As written*, you already have a dictionary, but that only remains necessarily true as long as the keys and values are simple values. That would be true still if the real addresses were, say, memory addresses, but wouldn't be true if they were postal addresses, as those contain spaces.

Once you have a format that contains spaces, you're better off using `regexp` to do the parsing. Fortunately, that's *relatively* easy:

```
# Standard stanza for reading a file
set f [open input.txt]
set data [read $f]
close $f

# Use the foreach to drop the matched lines; we just want the parts of them
foreach {- k v} [regexp -all -inline -line {^(\w+)\s(.+)$} $data] {
    # Trim the whitespace from the value; that's usually the right thing to do
    dict set mydict $k [string trim $v]
}
```

The `-line` option makes the RE only match within a line; it's great for this sort of data as it means we don't need a separate `split $data \n`. Without it, we'd need:

```
foreach line [split $data \n] {
    if {[regexp {^(\w+)\s(.+)$} $data -> k v]} {
        dict set mydict $k [string trim $v]
    }
}
```

That works, but it's usually a better plan to hoist as much work into command implementations as possible.

Comment: Hi Donal,
Quick question - what do I need to add to the code in order to take a "key" argument from the user and print out the value?

What I have in mind is something like this:
set val [dict get $addr_map [lindex $argv 0]]
puts $val

Here, addr_map is the dictionary name. And this is a .tcl file so when I call this file I'd be using this command:

source test.tcl key1

Will this work?